How do i securely use AdMob and Google Maps APIs into my Android project?
I'm currently integrating AdMob and Google Maps APIs into my Android project. After researching online, I encountered conflicting advice. Some suggest storing API keys in local.properties, while others indicate it's solely for Git or project sharing. Is there a recommended approach endorsed by the Android community for securely storing and accessing these API keys in the manifest file? Despite exploring various Stack Overflow threads, I haven't found a solution tailored to my needs. I'd greatly appreciate a detailed answer addressing this issue. Thank you.
